# Find pth percentile of a stream of numbers

Tags: streaming-algorithm

I want to find the pth percentile of a stream of integers, exactly (not approximately).

If we know the number of integers which will be coming in the stream and the numbers can fit into the memory then we can simply sort the integers and find the pth percentile.

But, what if all the numbers can't be fit in memory?  How can we do that?

We can assume all integers are 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not possible to solve this problem with above conditions. Sooner or later, while reading next element from stream, you will run out of memory and will have to throw away one of buffered elements. But without having any constraints on further elements in stream, it is always possible to construct such sequence of further elements in stream, so that thrown out element is the searched one.

A practical commercial-grade solution exists, though it produces approximate result:

1. Allocate memory for as many numbers as you can afford
2. Use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) atop of allocated memory to sample numbers from stream
3. When end of stream is reached, search for percentile among samples

To get exact solution, you need to either know number of elements in advance, or to have enough memory, or to have knowledge of stream properties (e.g. stream is monotonic). Keywords are "running median" and "n-th order statistics".

Comment: If I know the number of elements in advance, how is that going to help? For example - if stream consists of 100 numbers and only 10 can be fit in memory at a time, how can I use this information to calculate percentile?

Comment: Existence of such algorithm depends on what percentile you need to find. If you need to find some percentile >=90% then you simply keep largest 10 elements during iteration over stream (use heap for that). Same is true for percentiles <=10%. For percentiles >10% and <90% I don't know general algorithm.